# Filter array with regex using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter

I am not very well versed with coding. I have a set of strings in an array and I am trying to filter them out using regex but it's not working for me. I want my result array to return any string containing _*number* like _0, _01, _000

and the filter that I am using is

```js
var myArray = ["bedroom_01", "bedroom_02", "bedroom" , "bathroom_01"];

var result = myArray.filter(name => name.includes("/_\d+/g"));

console.log(result);
```

The above code is returning me a blank array. Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"/_\d+/g"` -> `/_\d+/g` you're passing a string instead of a regex. EDIT: also you cannot use a regex in `.inclues`, you need to do `regex.test(string)`.

Comment: That ain't a reg exp, that be a string and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) does not use a reg exp.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks folks!

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need `RegExp#test` with a regex literal:

```js
var myArray = ["bedroom_01", "bedroom_02", "bedroom" , "bathroom_01"];
console.log(
   myArray.filter(name => /_\d+/.test(name))
)
```

If you need to check if the array item ends with `_` + digits, use `/_\d+$/`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are passing to includes is a string not a regexp and includes takes a string not a regexp instead you can use the `match` method

```js
var myArray = ["bedroom_01", "bedroom_02", "bedroom" , "bathroom_01"];

var result = myArray.filter(name => name.match(/_\d+/));

console.log(result);
```